# How to make a query with usage of like operator over a string collection in GORM

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

Assume a domain class called *User*. *User* class looks like this:

```
class User {
     List<String> values
}
```

The collection *values* contains strings like "http://example.com/x", "http://google.com/y", "http://google.com/z" and so on...

Let's say we want to build a query which gets all the users that have specific string in the collection *values* (e.g. "google.com"). Something like this:

```
def criteria = User.createCriteria()
def results = criteria.listDistinct () {
  and {
    user.values.each {  like('someField', '%${it}%') }
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You should post your answer as an actual answer and accept it.

Comment: I think the 'in' predicate of the criteria builder might lead to a more concise solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the answer by experimentation. The solution is:

```
def criteria = User.createCriteria()
def results = criteria.listDistinct () {
  and {
    user.values.each {  like('someField', '%'+it+'%') }
  }
}
```

Comment: This works great and is the only solution I've seen to my problem, which is: I have an array of strings which are keywords in a search, and I need to do an ilike condition for them all in an AND block.  Wish I could upvote this more!

Comment: Hi Ondrej, what is somefield. Bz it is list of strings right?pls explain.

Comment: Hi. "someField" represents value inside "user.values" in this case. I think you can name it how ever you want...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are doing with your suggested answer. 
I have never seen that usage of each in the criteria query before.

This question has been asked many times before but never given an answer. 
The problem is that you are queriyng a String association, which is not a domain class. If you would make your own String domain class for example ondrej.String { String strValue } then you would be able to do :

```
User.withCriteria {

 values { ilike("strValue", "...") }

}
```

The problem is not having access to the value of the String object. The value of the String class is called value, but it is a char array, so I do not believe the following will work:

```
User.withCriteria {

 values { ilike("value", "...") }

}
```

You could try using :

```
User.withCriteria {

 values { ilike("toString", "...") }

}
```

or something else instead of toString ... I do not have the possibility to test this right now.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to replace "..." with some field/variable. e.g. User user = new User("name"); User.withCriteria {
 values { like("name", user.getName()) }
}; So the solution is: '%'+user.getName()+'%'

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trying and researching, I found this will work with Grails 2.4.0, I don't know about older versions.

```
Cat.withCriteria {
    createAlias('nicknames', 'n') 
    ilike 'n.elements', '%kitty%'
}
```

The trick is to use 'n.**elements**'